# Algorithm for grouping by overlapping date ranges

Tags: algorithm, date, grouping

What is the best algorithm to group data by overlapping date ranges?

*Input data*:
An array of objects consisting from 3 fields: start (format YYYY-MM-DD), end (format YYYY-MM-DD), name.
Input data is sorted by start date.

*Output data*:
An array of objects consisting from 3 fields: start (format YYYY-MM-DD), end (format YYYY-MM-DD), data (array).

Input example:

```
[
    {
        start: 2021-10-01,
        end: 2022-10-01,
        name: data_1
    },
    {
        start: 2021-11-01,
        end: 2022-02-01,
        name: data_2
    },
    {
        start: 2021-12-01,
        end: 2022-01-01,
        name: data_3
    }
]
```

Output example:

```
[
    {
        start: 2021-10-01,
        end: 2021-10-31,
        data:
        [
            data_1
        ]
    },
    {
        start: 2021-11-01,
        end: 2021-11-30,
        data:
        [
            data_1,
            data_2
        ]
    },
    {
        start: 2021-12-01,
        end: 2022-01-01,
        data:
        [
            data_1,
            data_2,
            data_3
        ]
    },
    {
        start: 2022-01-02,
        end: 2022-02-01,
        data:
        [
            data_1,
            data_2,
        ]
    },
    {
        start: 2022-02-02,
        end: 2022-10-01,
        data:
        [
            data_1
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Create a list with two events for each object in the original list, one for "start" and one for "end." Sort that new list by time. Think about what action needs to be taken at each event encountered in such a list while traversing.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Sorry, I forgot to add one more condition that input data is sorted by "start". Now I added it to the description.
Unfortunately, I did not understand your comment. As I understand it, I already have a list (input) with two events ("start" and "end"), right?

Comment: No, you have a list with two events per object. I'm suggesting to create a list with two separate events per object in the original list, one event for "start" and one for "end," and sort and iterate over that.

Comment: Transform [{start: x, end: y, name: z}] into [{start: x, name: z}, {end: y, name: z}] and sort and iterate by time.

Comment: @Alexey - What do you require from an algorithm in order to be considered _the best algorithm_?